# Delete or Redefine angular module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

with the following I would like to be able to define a module the first time and then change it on the fly later on. The reason is that my modules are dynamically generated and I'd rather reload one module than the whole app once One JavaScript file changes; it is Huge and Slow to load. The JS files are watched for changes and loaded lazily but always the initial module persists, i.e. 'This will be logged the first time' always gets logged even though the new JavaScript executes it does not overwrite the old module.

I think this would be a great tool for the AngularJS community but I don't know as yet it if it's already possible (I keep reading it's not). Alternatively I'd be happy if I could achieve the same using controllers/directives/1.5components

Thank you

```js
// First state of angular module
angular.module('myApp.view1', [])
.controller('View1Ctrl', ['$scope',function($scope) {
  $scope.buttonClick = function () {
    console.log('This will be logged first time');
  }
}]);


// Second state of angular module
angular.module('myApp.view1', [])
.controller('View1Ctrl', ['$scope',function($scope) {
  $scope.buttonClick = function () {
    console.log('This will be logged the second time');
  }
}]);
```

```html
<button ng-click="buttonClick()">Button</button>
```

Comment: This seems like an odd requirement. Why is your code being regenerated so frequently that you would need to reload it in-place? Seems like it would be wiser to design your components with dynamic functionality that can adjust to changes on the server. Or perhaps have them consume an external library and you could regenerate and lazily replace _that_.

Comment: I know it seems odd without explaining my use case, but I think this opens up a whole new world of possibilities for angular. The main issue, though, is that  I don't want to reload the site each time a module changes. I need to inject it only. This is more for a development tool. Perhaps similar to what Webpack is doing with their hot module replacement

Answer (score 0):

However that's not a groovy thing to redefine your angular module.

You can do that by just defining the `angular.module('YourAppModule', ['Dependencies']);`

This will overwrite your previously bootstrapped module.

Comment: I've tried this before, but unfortunately it is not working as I'd expect as I explain in the post. Here is someone else's attempt at the same thing that illustrates the problem: http://jsbin.com/xukafo

Answer (score 0):

I have made a feature request for this issue, but unfortunately it's been denied, understandably so. Further details are here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/14743#issuecomment-224868610